# How do I make interwoven symbols on Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Sorta like this, but with actual depth (the lines crossing over and under each other):

[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck with this? Show us some of the tests you did and what didn't work!

Comment: I have no idea where to begin actually. Actions like sending the figure to the top/bottom move the whole thing, when I need just a segment to remain on wither layer.

Comment: Just to clarify: the shape consists in two interwoven letters "b", one segment passing below and the other above the other letter.

Comment: Maybe start with your 2 figures, join them and "slice" them apart. That's probably how a lot of us would get started, then the rest is tweaking everything using the basic vector tools. You don't need to re-invent the wheel so if your 2 B can fit together somehow, that's a big part of the work done. I don't use Inkscape unfortunately so I can't give you precise names of the basic tools I'm talking about! But give it a try and post your tests, then someone who knows Inkscape might be able to give you some clues!

Comment: You can also play with symmetry using [tiled clones](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Tiles.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with the **[knot](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-Knot.html) path effect**:

[image: Knot path effect]